# How can I get the APP SECRET of an application that I created programatically?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created a FB App programatically using this:

https://www.facebook.com/connect/create_app.php?api_key=APP_ID&name=AP_NAME

now I need to get the APP ACCESS TOKEN that can be retrieved using the following code:

```
$APPLICATION_ID = "APP_ID";
$APPLICATION_SECRET = "APP_SECRET";

$token_url =    "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" .
                "client_id=" . $APPLICATION_ID .
                "&client_secret=" . $APPLICATION_SECRET .
                "&grant_type=client_credentials";
$app_token = file_get_contents($token_url);
```

for that, I obviously need to have first the APP_SECRET...

So is there any workaround to get the APP_SECRET of the newly created app?

Answer (score 2):

Your AppSecret is used for "security purposes" and should not be retrieved that way.

The Appsecret is used to encrypt and decrypt your requests as defined on `oauth` handshake mechanisms.

It's not supposed to have "realtime mechanisms via api" to getit: do you realize the security issues that it could generate?

Try to look for the secret_key by other perspective, that's the kind of information that no one whats to have on the wire...

hope helps your Vision/Needs

Comment: Thanks Flavio, I do realize it's used for security purposes... however the major reason I need it is to get the APP_ACCESS_TOKEN. So Is there any other method to get the APP_ACCESS_TOKEN of the newly created app?

This is what it typically returns when a new app is created programatically:


#{"new_app_id"%3A434removed939668%2C"new_api_key"%3A"876removed3524a02320c7b0f71e"}


I'm not really sure on how to use the "new_api_key" for that purpose.

P.S.: Sorry guys, I can't figure out how to format the code here in comments... tried many times.

Comment: OK, accesstoken is generated on your oauth provider (fb on this case) and sent to you during the handshake process. but to make the request to obtain that, as you said, you must to have it first. did you taked a look to the Facebook API to check if they returns tis value on some method related with your operation?

Comment: I've read documentation dozens of times but it just doesn't make any sense to me or im missing something here. I'm not very experienced with that but I have been developing apps for some months now.
And searching "How to get application access token" doesn't seem to return any valuable resource from google...

Answer (score 1):

You must go to [Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) and copy both keys:[image]

Comment: I suspect if he's creating the app programmatically he'd like to get the secret key that way too.

Comment: Yeah, Ceejayoz is right. I need to get this programmatically because my script creates an app for my client, then I get the new APP ID... etc. Then I need to edit the editable fields of the newly created app, programmatically through FB API. The point here is for my script to make the most configurations so my client does not have to, thus avoiding possible errors and efforts from the client...

Of course I could redirect them to the App Settings page and they could edit the settings but that's not very practical from the client point of view..

Comment: You have to do it that way, or ask the user to copy/paste their details

Comment: Ok, there is a time that I don't work with FB, but I believe that your approach is incorrect. A programatically created app should no need a secret key or at least it should not can be requested via API. All secrets token generally stay in a secure place (owner's account, electronic wallet, etc).